# E: Unable to locate package language-pack-en-base

Tags: php, debian

i am trying to upgrade to PHP 7.0 on my debian 8 computer using this guide:https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

when i run sudo LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0 i get this output:

> You are about to add the following PPA to your system:
>        PPA with PHP 7.0.  If you want a co-installable version of PHP, please use:
>
> ```
> ppa:ondrej/php
>
> where PHP 7.0 and PHP 5.6 co-exists.
>
> You can get more information about the packages at https://deb.sury.org
>
> For PHP 5.6 use: ppa:ondrej/php5-5.6
> For PHP 5.5 use: ppa:ondrej/php5
> For PHP 5.4 use: ppa:ondrej/php5-oldstable
>
> BUGS&FEATURES: This PPA now has a issue tracker: https://deb.sury.org/pages/bugreporting.html
>
> PLEASE READ: If you like my work and want to give me a little motivation, please consider donating:
> ```
>
> https://deb.sury.org/pages/donate.html
>
> ```
> WARNING: add-apt-repository is broken with non-UTF-8 locales, see https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/56 for workaround:
>
> # apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base
> # LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php-7.0
>  More info: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php-7.0
> Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it
>
> gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmplffxdbmn/secring.gpg' created
> gpg: keyring `/tmp/tmplffxdbmn/pubring.gpg' created
> gpg: requesting key E5267A6C from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
> gpg: /tmp/tmplffxdbmn/trustdb.gpg: trustdb created
> gpg: key E5267A6C: public key "Launchpad PPA for Ond\xc5\x99ej Sur�" imported
> gpg: Total number processed: 1
> gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
> Exception in thread Thread-1:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
>     self.run()
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 153, in run
>     self.add_ppa_signing_key(self.ppa_path)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 250, in add_ppa_signing_key
>     tmp_export_keyring, signing_key_fingerprint, tmp_keyring_dir):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 202, in _verify_fingerprint
>     got_fingerprints = self._get_fingerprints(keyring, keyring_dir)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 194, in _get_fingerprints
>     output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, universal_newlines=True)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 609, in check_output
>     output, unused_err = process.communicate(inputdata, timeout=timeout)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 947, in communicate
>     stdout = _eintr_retry_call(self.stdout.read)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/subprocess.py", line 491, in _eintr_retry_call
>     return func(*args)
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
>     return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 92: ordinal not in range(128)
> ```

so i tried the workaround suggested by the guide using this command: sudo apt-get install -y language-pack-en-base and I get this error:

> W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://debian.linux.edu.lv/debian/
>   jessie/main amd64 Packages
>   (/var/lib/apt/lists/debian.linux.edu.lv_debian_dists_jessie_main_binary-amd64_Packages)
>       W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
>       E: Unable to locate package language-pack-en-base

Comment: Well, I think you are trying to add an ubuntu repository to a debian sources list. That can't work. Use the repositories of dotdeb.org

Comment: Oh. Well i feel super stupid now. Anyway a big thanks to you, kind sir :).

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this on Ubuntu 14.04 and PHP 7.2 from ppa:ondrej/php was to add this earlier in my setup script:

```
export LC_ALL=C.UTF-8
```

This was the output of my `locale -a` command right before I changed the environment variable:

```
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
```

Hope this helps.